# give a crawler pure html as opposed to trigger ajax

Tags: html, ajax, web-crawler

If my site is being crawled what PHP method should I use so that although ajax will not be triggered, my content will be transmitted?

PHP cannot detect whether I have ajax capabilities.

**Goal: to give the crawler plain html.**

I checked suggested answers by I'm still lost.

Comment: If you are crawling using `curl` or `file_get_contents()` or an equivalent, you will never have AJAX capabilities. AJAX is Javascript which relies on a browser's JS engine.

Answer (score 1):

Google has specifications on this utilizing hashbangs (`#!`). See here: http://moz.com/blog/how-to-allow-google-to-crawl-ajax-content

Also note that `<noscript>` is an option, although PHP inserted will be transmitted regardless of JavaScript.

Finally, there are the general principles of Progressive Enhancement. Make your page fully functional without AJAX: pagination with actual links, PHP insertion of results, etc.

Then if JavaScript is available, hijack the links to pull in content without navigating away from the page.